# Mockito is not mocking out a member variable method return value

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have the following class that contains a member variable, but Mockito can't seem to mock the member variable's methods. Below is my System Under Test:

```
public class MessageConsumer {

    private ConsumerResponse consumerResponse;
    private NotificationConsumer notificationConsumer;

    @Scheduled(cron = "${com.example.value}")
    public void fetch() {
        consumerResponse = notificationConsumer.fetchWithReturnConsumerResponse(); //no exception thrown on this line at all -- but could this be the cause of the problem in the test?
        System.out.println("consumerResponse's responseCode: " + consumerResponse.getResponseCode()); // NullPointerException thrown here
    }

    public ConsumerResponse setConsumerResponse(ConsumerResponse consumerResponse) {
        this.consumerResponse = consumerResponse;
    }

    public ConsumerResponse getConsumerResponse() {
        return consumerResponse;
    }
}
```

And the following is the relevant JUnit test for the class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MessageConsumerTest {

    @Mock
    private ConsumerResponse consumerResponse;

    @InjectMocks
    private MessageConsumer messageConsumer;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    //Failing unit test
    @Test
    public void getResponseCodeShouldReturn200() {
        Mockito.when(consumerResponse.getResponseCode()).thenReturn("200");
        messageConsumer.fetch()
    }

}
```

As you can see, I've mocked the `ConsumerResponse consumerResponse` variable to return `"200"` when the `consumerResponse.getResponseCode()` method gets invoked.  Instead, I'm getting a `NullPointerException`.

I'm pretty sure I mocked the member variable correctly and initialized it appropriately (`initMocks`).  I've spent days trying to figure this out. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: can you share ConsumerResponse class?

Comment: @GauravRai1512 It's in an external library that I unfortunately do not have access to

Comment: @JB Nizet But that shouldn't matter since the method I'm mocking out belongs to the consumerResponse object, right? -- isn't that the whole point of Mockito? (to isolate dependencies and make them do what you want them to?)

Comment: You're using notificationConsumer in your code, but it isn't mocked. So it's null. The SpringBootTest annotation is useless, too, since you're not running your test with the SpringRunner. So it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Precisely: you want to isolate the class under test (MessageConsumer) from its dependencies (NotificationConsumer). So you need to mock NotificationConsumer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `NotificationConsumer` is also an external dependency for this class, you have to also mock this class as otherwise `consumerResponse = notificationConsumer.fetchWithReturnConsumerResponse();` will result into `null` within your test as you didn't mock the `NotificationConsumer`. In addition I would suggest not to use `@SpringBootTest` within this **unit** test as this annotation will boot the whole Spring context. The following snippet should help you:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MessageConsumerTest {

    @Mock
    private ConsumerResponse consumerResponse;

    @Mock
    private NotificationConsumer notificationConsumer;

    @InjectMocks
    private MessageConsumer messageConsumer;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void getResponseCodeShouldReturn200() {
        Mockito.when(notificationConsumer.fetchWithReturnConsumerResponse()).thenReturn(consumerResponse);
        Mockito.when(consumerResponse.getResponseCode()).thenReturn("200");
        messageConsumer.fetch();
    }

}
```